# Generic collection with wildcard and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, generics, jpa

What is the best way to manage generic collection with wildcard in Hibernate mapping? 
For example, I have a `ComponentParent`, `ComponentChild` and `Container` classes. If I try the example below I get error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined
```

The entities are

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@Table(name = "COMPONENT")
class abstract ComponentParent {
    private Long id;

    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(name = "CHILD")
class ComponentChild extends ComponentParent {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTAINER")
class abstract Container {
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "containerId")
    private List<? extends ComponentParent> components;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CONC")
class ConcreteContainer {

    public List<ChildComponents> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to keep it as "generic collection with wildcard"? When you access it you will anyway need to have some logic to deal with each object based on type don't you?

Can't you keep the List of components in Container as

```
private List<ComponentParent> components;
```

And use a Strategy based on which type of ComponentXXX where the list is being used.

(BTW I assume class ComponentChild extends ComponentParent.)

Comment: Hi you're right ComponentChild extends ComponentParent (I've corrected it). I've updated the question with way I want to deal with object type. I want implementation of Container which knows about concrete component type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can acheive that easily with Hibernate/JPA. I'd be interested if you find a solution too.

However, if it's up to me I'd probably do something like below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="xxx")
@Table(name = "CONTAINER")
class abstract Container {
    private Long id;

    abstract public List<? extends ComponentParent> getComponents();
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CONC")
class ConcreteContainer {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "containerId")
    private List<ChildComponents> components;

    @Overrides
    public List<ChildComponents> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

}
```

Then there could be another

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CONC2")
class ConcreteContainer2 {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "containerId")
    private List<OtherComponents> components;

    @Overrides
    public List<OtherComponents> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

}
```

where OtherComponent extends ComponentParent.